# Using HTML `&thinsp;` breaks editing for the whole line in Safari

Tags: bug, markdown, editor, safari

Recently I had an edit to [one of my answers](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/41552/revisions) approved by two other users which left me wondering why. I wasn't able to see any difference between `&thinsp;` and `&nbsp;`. Neither in the rendered output nor in any of the other available views.

Another user, also on Mac, rejected the edit.
Then another edit was made that also introduced no visible change for me with the comment "deleted 1 character in body".

View in Safari Version 11.0.3 (12604.5.6.1.1):
[image]

View in Firefox 59.0b8 (64-bit):
[image]

Comments on that post and own experiments indicated that depending on platform the rendering of both editor and rendered output differ way too much as to paint any real representation of consistency.

When I try to edit both versions of suggested edits the behaviour of the editor in Safari gets out of whack, the cursor is no longer representative of point of character entry.